# migrating wordpress, but getting some php parsing errors

Tags: php, migration

I have successfully migrated wordpress site to my localhost using "All-in-One WP Migration" plugin.

But I am getting errors on some pages:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\XXX\XXXXpage.php on line 112

editing that file, there is some hard-to-read 'if else' statement wih 'HTML tags'

one error I have fixed was changing

```
<?if (!is_mobile() && !is_tablet()){?>
```

to

```
<?php if (!is_mobile() && !is_tablet()){?>
```

anybody knows why the first statement worked on my web, but not on localhost? perhaps due to some PHP version?

Comment: This [great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019696/what-is-the-difference-between-the-php-open-tags-and-php) have all hints about the difference between  the short `<?` and long `<?php` php tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some PHP versions require the explicit declaration of `<?php`   instead of just  `<?` declarations or the other way around. Settings such as `short_open_tag`  in your php.ini file.

You can read more here http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: thank you, @codiiv ! :)
this has fixed all other parsing errors

Comment: Glad I can help

Answer (score 0):

`PHP Short Tags` are enabled on your web server & its disabled on your `localhost`.
the solution is to either turn on short tags or write full code.

**Solution One** Enable short tags.

- open up `php.ini` file
- set `short_open_tag=On`
- and Restrat Apache server

**Solution two** replace short tags with full